# How to create a changeset explicitly in RTC scm?

Tags: code

In RTC scm, when I first checkin a file to workspace, a new changeset is created, but subsequent checkin all go into this same changeset, how can I create a second changeset when I checkin another file?

That is, suppose I modified two files, f1 and f2. After checkin f1, changeset c1 created by RTC, when I checkin f2, I want it to go to another changeset instead of c1, how can I achieve it?

BTW, I am using scm.sh, not eclipse, so please use scm.sh command, not eclipse menu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case solved.
Using scm.sh create changeset.